# Java addActionListener(this) creates error

Tags: java, button, compiler-errors

When I try to add an ActionListener following an example I found online, it shows an error message saying "Cannot use this in a static context."  Is there any workaround for this, or should I try a different approach entirely?

```
        //Variable Declaration 
    Drink drink = new Drink(); 

    //Create type1Button 
    JButton type1Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[1]); 
    type1Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    type1Button.setActionCommand("drink1");

    //Create type2Button 
    JButton type2Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[2]); 
    type2Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_2); 
    type2Button.setActionCommand("drink2"); 

    //Create type3Button 
    JButton type3Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[3]); 
    type3Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_3); 
    type3Button.setActionCommand("drink3");

    //Create type4Button 
    JButton type4Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[4]); 
    type4Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_4);
    type4Button.setActionCommand("drink4");

    //Create type5Button 
    JButton type5Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[5]); 
    type5Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_5); 
    type5Button.setActionCommand("drink5"); 

    //Create Action Listeners 
    type1Button.addActionListener(this); 
    type2Button.addActionListener(this); 
    type3Button.addActionListener(this); 
    type4Button.addActionListener(this); 
    type5Button.addActionListener(this);
```

Edit:

```
    public final void createListeners (JButton type1Button, JButton type2Button, JButton type3Button, JButton type4Button, JButton type5Button) {
    //Create Action Listeners 
    type1Button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
    type2Button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
    type3Button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
    type4Button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
    type5Button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
}
```

The problem now is when I try to use this in the static void main, it complains that I cannot make a static reference to a non static method, but how else can I run it?

Comment: Can you include the whole code

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot use this in a static context" means that you are referencing the current instance of the class (i.e. `this`) inside a `static` method. A static method is bound to a class and not an instance, so you cannot reference `this` in that case.

You should change your method to be non-`static` and call it against an instance of your class.

Example:

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener {

   ...

   private JButton type1Button;
   private JButton type2Button;
   private JButton type3Button;
   private JButton type4Button;
   private JButton type5Button;

   public MyClass() {
      ..
      Drink drink = new Drink(); 

      //Create type1Button 
      type1Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[1]); 
      type1Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_1);
      type1Button.setActionCommand("drink1");

      //Create type2Button 
      type2Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[2]); 
      type2Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_2); 
      type2Button.setActionCommand("drink2"); 

      //Create type3Button 
      type3Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[3]); 
      type3Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_3); 
      type3Button.setActionCommand("drink3");

      //Create type4Button 
      type4Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[4]); 
      type4Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_4);
      type4Button.setActionCommand("drink4");

      //Create type5Button 
      type5Button = new JButton (drink.typeArray[5]); 
      type5Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_5); 
      type5Button.setActionCommand("drink5"); 

      //Create Action Listeners 
      createListeners (type1Button, type2Button, type3Button, type4Button, type5Button);
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The problem was I was trying to create the listeners inside public static void main.  I've now created a method to do this instead with the following code.  Please let me know if it will work, for I can't test it until I add what the buttons need to do.  Code is in edit in question.

Comment: @DJOwen Well you can call the method in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

make the method non-static.  there is no "this" in a static context, it makes no sense.  you either need to pass in the component you want use, in place of "this", OR you need to make the enclosing method non-static.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

What the `.addActionListener()` method expects to receive is an instance of a class that implements the `ActionListener` interface. In other words, it wants something that can be used to pass the events to when they happen.

But the word `this` in Java refers to an instance of a class only when it's used from inside a method or constructor of a class. A class can have instance methods, but it can also have `static` methods; these `static` methods aren't attached to any particular instance, but just define things that are related to the class in general. So if you had a class `Dog`, for instance, you might have an instance method of `.woof()`, that would enable a particular instance of `Dog` to woof; but you might also have other `static` methods like `.listDoggyTreats()` that would do something doggy-related, but not tied to a *specific* dog.

What you're doing is calling `.addActionListener(this)` from a `static` method. You're therefore trying to tell Java to use the current instance of your class as an `ActionListener` when **there is no current instance**, because it's executing from a `static` method.

To fix it, you need one of two approaches:

1. Don't declare your method as `static`. You will then also need to make sure that the class implements the `ActionListener` interface.
2. Use a separate instance of a separate `ActionListener` implementation to pass instead of `this`.

Either is a reasonable thing to do, though if your method is doing this kind of thing (manipulating buttons and so on), it's probably indicative of problems in your code if it's `static`. That's where you should focus your attention first.